# Create ENUM(-like) type of object values

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have an object

```
const modalTypes = {
  newPizza: 'NEW_PIZZA',
  newCola: 'NEW_COLA',
  newCustom: 'NEW_CUSTOM,
}
```

Then I have an action creator that takes an action that is one of the `modalTypes`' values.

```
const showModal = (modalType: ModalType, body: BodyType) => {
  // do something...
}

// e.g.
showModal('NEW_PIZZA', ...)
```

How to get the `ModalType` to be `NEW_PIZZA | NEW_COLA | NEW_CUSTOM`?

---

Something similar to this, but for values.

```
const Foo = { a: 'FOO', b: 'BAR', c: 'BAZ' };
type Abc = keyof typeof Foo

Abc = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
// Desired = 'FOO' | 'BAR' | 'BAZ'
```

Comment: Even if you could do this, I think that the types would be `string` rather than literals like `'NEW_PIZZA'`. I think an emum may work best here if you could make that change.

Comment: why not declare an enum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without extra assertions in 3.4 (unreleased yet, try it using `npm install typescript@next`) using a `as const` assertions, see [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29510).

```
const modalTypes = {
  newPizza: 'NEW_PIZZA',
  newCola: 'NEW_COLA',
  newCustom: 'NEW_CUSTOM',
} as const

type ModalType = typeof modalTypes[keyof typeof modalTypes]
```

Below 3.4, I still would not go the explicit assertion route, I would rather use a helper function to infer the correct types, it can be an IIFE:

```
const modalTypes = (<V extends string, T extends Record<string, V>>(o:T) => o)({
  newPizza: 'NEW_PIZZA',
  newCola: 'NEW_COLA',
  newCustom: 'NEW_CUSTOM',
})

type ModalType = typeof modalTypes[keyof typeof modalTypes]
```

Comment: Wow, that first example is super sleek! Can you point to a specific change in 3.4 that allows this? Anyway, I have never thought about using IIFEs like that. Pure wizardry!

Comment: @Qwerty added a link to the PR, sorry I unusually try to add references, missed this one :) (there was even a `,` where I meant to add it :D)

Answer (score 1):

As @ExplosionPills says without extra annotation the type of values is generalized, but if you are OK adding annotation this works:

```
const modalTypes = {
  newPizza: 'NEW_PIZZA' as 'NEW_PIZZA',
  newCola: 'NEW_COLA' as 'NEW_COLA',
  newCustom: 'NEW_CUSTOM' as 'NEW_CUSTOM',
}

type ModalType = typeof modalTypes[keyof typeof modalTypes]
```

Answer (score 1):

In case when ModalType is collection of string constants you need to use Enum instead of object like this:

```
enum ModalType {
    newPizza = "NEW_PIZZA",
    newCola = "NEW_COLA",
    newCustom = "NEW_CUSTOM",
}
const showModal = (modalType: ModalType[keyof ModalType]) => {
    // do something...
};
showModal("NEW_PIZZA");
```